# Gdal crashes when creating geometry from json

Tags: python, json, gdal, ogr

I want to create a geometry from a `geojson` file. 
I load the file with the `json` library in python 2.7, then use this [line](https://pcjericks.github.io/py-gdalogr-cookbook/geometry.html#create-geometry-from-geojson)

```
point = ogr.CreateGeometryFromJson(geojson)
```

to convert.

This line is from the `ogr` library which depends on the `GDAL` Library (Version GDAL/OGR 1.11.3-1)
When I run this line, python crashes. I only get `Segmentation fault: 11`.

The `geojson` looks something like this:

```
"type": "FeatureCollection",
"crs": { "type": "name", "properties": { "name": "someCRS" } },

"features": [
{ "type": "Feature", "properties": { "value1": "x", "value2": 886, "value3": 0, "value3": "y", "value4": "9878665", "value5": "91", "altitude": 0.000000, "feature": "y", "id": 4, "value6": 0, "value7": "xyz", "value8": 883645, "value9": 3.024 }, "geometry": { "type": "Point", "coordinates": [ 1, 1 ] } }
}]
```

Comment: can wee see the value of geojson

Comment: @Natecat added. There are more features in there, since its a feature collection, but thats about how it looks like

Comment: I haven't used json that much, so I'm not 100% sure on this, but shouldn't the last two characters in that json be switched

Comment: @Natecat sorry, that was a typo... When I validate the json (http://jsonlint.com) there is no error!

Comment: If you are 100% sure you are passing in valid json, I'd file a bug report [here](http://trac.osgeo.org/gdal/)